# Query on Parse relational data is not coming back ordered using orderedByAscending

Tags: ios, relational-database, parse-platform, pfquery

I'm querying relation data on parse and I would like the objects to come back ordered by the date they were created. I've had this method work before but haven't been able to get an ordered query using relational data. The query return is in a random order. Thanks in advance! Here's my code:

```
    PFQuery *postQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Post"];
    [roomQuery whereKey:@"name" equalTo:self.postName];

    NSError *error;
    //done on main thread to have data for next query
    NSArray *results = [postQuery findObjects:&error];

    PFObject *post;

    if ([results count]) {
        post = [results objectAtIndex:0];
        NSLog(@"results were found");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"results were not found");
    }

    PFRelation *commentsRelation = [@"Comments"];
    [commentsRelation.query orderByAscending:@"createdAt"];
    [commentsRelation.query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"Error Fetching Comments: %@", error);
        } else {
            NSArray *comments = objects; 
     }
```

Comment: I don't see anything wrong just reading the code.  Can you show us a sample of the data that is in comments?

Comment: "PFRelation *commentsRelation = [@"Comments"];"

This code shouldn't even compile, can you fix it to show how you get the commentsRelation?

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little confused by your code,

1. you create a "postQuery", and call it, but never use any of its data.
2. There's also a roomQuery that never seems to have been allocated, or used.
3. You're querying a specific post by its name. Are you controlling its name? If not, you should use id's
4. what is PFRelation commentsRelation = [@"Comments"];

Probably because it's just a snippet, this stuff is dealt with elsewhere; however, for my answer, I'm assuming that your "comments" field is an array of "Comment" class objects.

Option 1:

```
PFQuery * postQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Post"];
[postQuery whereKey:@"name" equalTo:self.postName]; 
// again, possibly an id field would be more reliable
// [postQuery whereKey:@"objectId" equalTo:self.postId];
[postQuery includeKey:@"Comments"];
PFObject * post = [postQuery getFirstObject];// no need to download all if you just want object at [0]
// this will contain your post and all of it's comments with only one api call
// unfortunately, it's not sorted, so you would have to run a sort.
NSArray * comments =  [post[@"Comments"] sortedArrayUsingComparator: ^(id obj1, id obj2) {
    return [obj1[@"createdAt" compare: obj2[@"createdAt"];
}];
```

Option 2:

Perhaps a better option is to rework your data structure and instead of associating the comments to the post, you could associate the post to the comments (as in the parse docs)

```
PFQuery * postQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Post"];
[postQuery whereKey:@"name" equalTo:self.postName]; 
// again, possibly an id field would be more reliable
// [postQuery whereKey:@"objectId" equalTo:self.postId];

PFQuery * commentQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Comment"];
[commentsQuery whereKey:@"parent" matchesQuery:postQuery]; // when creating a comment, set your post as its parent
[commentsQuery addOrderDescending:@"createdAt"]
[commentQuery findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *comments, NSError *error) {
    // comments now contains the comments for myPost
}];
```

Both of the above solutions avoid making extra unnecessary api calls (parse charges based on calls after all!).